# What the second part of Psalm 7:7 actually mean? Does that mean return them with favors/blessings?

Tags: psalms

I'm trying to get a better understanding of Psalm 7:7 verse.

I understand the author is saying in the first part of the verse which is letting the Lord's assembly or congregation of people surround The Lord, but I'm a little confused about the second part of the verse.

In Psalm 7:7 NASB, it says "return on high".  Does that mean return them with favors/blessings?

> Psalm 7:6-8 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 6  Arise, O Lord, in Your anger; Lift up Yourself against the rage of
>   my adversaries, And arouse Yourself [a]for me; You have appointed
>   judgment.
>   **7  Let the assembly of the peoples encompass You, And over [b]them return on high.** 8  The Lord judges the peoples; [c]Vindicate me, O
>   Lord, according to my righteousness and my integrity that is in me.
>
> Psalm 7:6-8 King James Version (KJV)
>
> 6 Arise, O Lord, in thine anger, lift up thyself because of the rage
>   of mine enemies: and awake for me to the judgment that thou hast
>   commanded.
>   **7 So shall the congregation of the people compass thee about: for
>   their sakes therefore return thou on high.**
>   8 The Lord shall judge the people: judge me, O Lord, according to my
>   righteousness, and according to mine integrity that is in me.
>
> Psalm 7:6-8 New King James Version (NKJV)
>
> 6  Arise, O Lord, in Your anger; Lift Yourself up because of the rage
>   of my enemies; Rise up [a]for me to the judgment You have commanded!
>   **7  So the congregation of the peoples shall surround You; For their sakes, therefore, return on high.** 8  The Lord shall judge the
>   peoples; Judge me, O Lord, according to my righteousness, And
>   according to my integrity within me.
>
> Psalm 7:6-8 English Standard Version (ESV)
>
> 6 Arise, O Lord, in your anger;
>       lift yourself up against the fury of my enemies;
>       awake for me; you have appointed a judgment. **7 Let the assembly of the peoples be gathered about you;
>       over it return on high.** 8 The Lord judges the peoples;
>       judge me, O Lord, according to my righteousness
>       and according to the integrity that is in me.
>
> Psalm 7:6-8 New International Version (NIV)
>
> 6  Arise, Lord, in your anger;
>       rise up against the rage of my enemies.
>       Awake, my God; decree justice. **7  Let the assembled peoples gather around you,
>       while you sit enthroned over them on high.** 8 
>       Let the Lord judge the peoples. Vindicate me, Lord, according to my righteousness,
>       according to my integrity, O Most High.

Answer (score 1):

For Ps 7:6, 7, I prefer the BSB here:

> Arise, O LORD, in Your anger;
>
> rise up against the fury of my enemies.
>
> Awake, my God, and ordain judgment.
>
> Let the assembled peoples gather around You;
>
> take Your seat over them on high.

Ps 7 is a prayer/Psalm of David:  David is asking the LORD for victory against his enemies.  David seeks purity and integrity so that the LORD will be his fortress and guard.  Note V8:

> The LORD judges the peoples; vindicate me, O LORD, according to my
> righteousness and integrity.

Thus, David does not request stronger and greater armies because he recognizes that with God, he is invincible.  However, David seeks personal integrity to be worthy of having God fight his battles.

In V6 & 7 David uses ancient battle language when he asks the LORD to rise up against the enemy and may the people surround their LORD (the true king of Israel) who is asked to direct the battle from the throne of heaven, ie, "on high".  This is typical of the ancients whose strength was vested in their king.  If the king were invincible, then that honor was shared by the people.  Since the LORD is directing the battle from "on high", Israel's king cannot be killed and so is invincible, provided the people remain faithful to God.

Again, the over-riding concern of David is the personal integrity and purity of those fighting in the LORD's battles.